Protagonist is a wizard or wizard's apprentice. They go clothes shopping and are given powerful psychedelic drugs while a tailor measues them
I think I am remembering a small part of a fantasy novel. I read it in the late eighties or early nineties. Two men go clothes shopping. At least one of them is a wizard. The other is originally from our world. The tailor gives them delicious food and psychedelic drugs. This keeps them entertained throughout the otherwise tedious process of being measured for a full set of clothes.
There are many intelligent talking animals in the magical world they are in.
The human from our world is asked what sign he was born under. This turns out not to be a question about astrology. He is being asked what business his parents ran, what sign was on their house. They ran a general store so he says he was born under the sign of the general store. The other misunderstands and thinks he means he was born in a military family.

I found it! It's Spellsinger by Alan Dean Foster.
The ridiculous scene in the tailor's shop is detailed below.

The fox put both paws on hips and stared intently at the otter. "I do not clothe monsters! I have created attire for some of the best-dressed citizens of Lynchbany, and beyond. I have made clothing for Madam Scorianza and her best girls, for the banker Flaustyn Wolfe, for members of the town council, and for our most prominent merchants and craftsmen, but I do not clothe monsters." Mudge leaned over in the chair and helped himself to a long thin stick from a nearby tall glass filled with them. "Look on it as a challenge, mate." He used a tiny flinted sparker to light the stick. "Listen," said Jon-Tom, "I don't want to cause any trouble." The fox took a wary step backward as that towering form moved nearer. "Mudge here thinks that... that..." He was indicating the otter, who was puffing contentedly on the thin stick. Smoke filled the room with a delightfully familiar aroma. "Say," said Jon-Tom, "do you suppose I could have one of those, uh, sticks?" "For the convenience o' the customers, lad." Mudge magnanimously passed over a stick along with his sparker. Jon-Tom couldn't see how it worked, but at this point was more than willing to believe it had been treated with a good fire spell. Several long puffs on the glowing stick more than relaxed him. Not everything in this world was as horrible as it seemed, he decided. It was smoking that had made him accessible to the questing thoughts of Clothahump. Perhaps smoking would let something send him home. Ten minutes later, he no longer cared. Reassured by both Mudge and the giant's dreamy responses, the grumbling fox was measuring Jon-Tom as the latter lay quite contentedly on the carpeted floor. Mudge lay next to him, the two of them considerably higher mentally than physically. The tailor, whose name was Carlemot, did not objeet to their puffing, which indicated either an ample supply of the powerful smokesticks or a fine sense of public relations, or both. He left them eventually, returning several hours later to find otter and man totally bombed. They still lay on the floor, and were currently speculating with great interest on the intricacies of the worm-holes in the wooden ceiling. It was only later that Jon-Tom had recovered sufficiently for a dressing. When he finally saw himself in the mirror, the shock shoved aside quite a bit of the haze. The indigo silk shirt felt like cool mist against his skin. It was tucked neatly into straight-legged pants which were a cross between denim and flannel. Both pants and shirt were secured with matching buttons of black leather. The jet leather vest was fringed around the bottom and decorated with glass beadwork. The cuffs of the pants were likewise fringed, though he couldn't tell this at first because they were stuffed into calf-high black leather boots with rolled tops. At first it seemed surprising that the tailor had managed to find any footgear at all to fit him, considering how much larger he was than the average local human. Then it occurred to him that many of the inhabitants were likely to have feet larger in proportion to their bodies than did men. A belt of metal links, silver or pewter, held up the pants, shone in sharp contrast to the beautifully iridescent hip-length cape of some green lizard leather. A pair of delicate but functional silver clips held the cape together at the collar. Despite Mudge's insistence, however, he categorically refused to don the orange tricornered cap. "I just don't like hats." "Such a pity." Carlemot's attitude had shifted from one of distress to one of considerable pride. "It really is necessary to complete the overall effect, which, if I may be permitted to say so, is striking as well as unique." Jon-Tom turned, watched the scales of the cape flare even in the dim light. "Sure as hell would turn heads in L.A." "Not bad," Mudge conceded. "Almost worth the price." "'Almost' indeed!" The fox was pacing round Jon-Tom, inspecting the costume for any defects or tears.

